# How to Get a Key value from a dictionary whose values are lists?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each key has several lists of data as its values like this

```
myDict = {'data1' : ['data_d','dataD']['data_e','dataE']['data_f','dataF']}
```

I want to be able to input one of the values in the list and then be given the key. This is so I can get the other value in the list now that I have the key.

I've tried

```
dataKey = (list(myDict.keys())[list(myDict.values()).index(dataD)])
```

but that didn't work

I've also tried

```
for k, v in myDict.items():
    if 'dataD' in v:
        print k
```

but that didn't work as well.

Side question, in the questions that I've looked through, I see people using the variable k and v a lot even without the OP mentioning them, so I am wondering if k and v are already set variable in dictionaries?

Comment: `myDict` is not defined using valid Python syntax

Comment: k and v are short names for Key and Value. They have no special meaning (i.e. they are normal variable names) but it's easier to understand what they refer to if you name them that way

Comment: should `myDict` be `myDict = {'data1' : [['data_d','dataD'],['data_e','dataE'],['data_f','dataF']]}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second attempt was almost right, but a nested `for` loop is needed to traverse the list-of-lists:

```
myDict = {'data1' : [['data_d','dataD'], ['data_e','dataE'], ['data_f','dataF']]}

for key, value in myDict.items():
    for sublist in value:
        if 'dataD' in sublist:
            print(key)  # -> data1
```

Using variables named `k`, and `v` with dictionaries is purely optional and aren't special properties—other than being very short abbreviations for "key" and "value".

Note that if only one match is ever expected to occur, the code could be made more efficient by stopping the search after one is found. Here's one way of doing that:

```
target = 'dataD'
try:
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        for sublist in value:
            if target in sublist:
                print(key)  # -> data1
                raise StopIteration  # found, so quit searching
except StopIteration:
    pass  # found
else:
    print('{} not found'.format(target))
```

Answer (score 0):

if they are all going to be lists then you can do something like this (if i am understanding correctly)

```
myDict = {
        'data1': [['data_d','dataD'], ['data_e','dataE'], ['data_f','dataF']],
        }

def find(dic, item):
    for k, v in dic.items():
        for ls in v:
            if item in ls:
                return k
    return False

print(find(myDict, "data_d"))
# OUT [data1]
```

Comment: This seems to have worked! Thank you very much! I don't understand though, does python automatically understand that k and v stands for the key and values in the dictionary? I never defined them anywhere else. Or is the structure you used defined to be key and value already? Could I have done say 'for fruit, apple in dic.items():' instead and it still would've worked?

Comment: yes you could call it poop and pee for all it matters